# How to turn a vectorgraph into raster correctly?

Tags: qgis, raster, vector

In QGIS2.8 version, I added several points in a point vectorgraph. When using the grid - > Conversion - > rasterized vector , The results turn out into a black figure. How to turn a vectorgraph into raster correctly?

Comment: What do you mean by a vectorgraph? What do you want to accomplish? Going from vector points to raster usually means using an interpolation. Menu Raster > Interpolation > Interpolation.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to rasterize a vector layer (including points) is modifying the command line into the rasterize's window for aligning it perfectly to raster base. In metadata of raster base you can get Layer Extent and Pixel Size.

In the next image, I have a raster base (dem) and a vector point layer.

[image]

For the raster:

```
Pixel Size
73.9887 73.9887
Layer Extent
354971.3488602247089148 4414903.3223166307434440 479272.4038835020037368 4473428.4023900907486677
```

To modify the command: click in the pencil icon in the right side (see below image).

[image]

When you click in OK really get as result a black raster. However, the points were rasterized.

[image]

Then, change raster properties to Singleband Pseudocolor with, for example, 5 classes and zoom in an arbitrary zone of the map (as in the below image). You will able to observe that the points effectively were rasterized and their values, in this case, they were taken from the id field.

[image]